# Running pt-table-checksum on a table in different databases

Tags: mysql, percona-tools

I'm using filters for replication:

```
replicate-wild-do-table = test_slave.%
replicate-rewrite-db = test->test_slave
```

Is there an option to specify different DB name on slave for "pt-table-checksum"

```
pt-table-checksum --host=localhost --databases=test --max-load=Threads_connected:25 --no-check-replication-filters
```

EDIT 1:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test_slave';
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      145 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM percona.checksums;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|       40 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT 2:

```
# ls -l *.frm | wc -l
145
# ls -l | awk '{print $3,$4}' | uniq

mysql mysql
```

It's also complaining that two tables have no indexes and are oversized. It looks like it's just skipping some tables?

Comment: Are there tables with no primary keys and unique keys ?

Comment: Yes, there is few tables (~10) without indexes, I've tried to checksum table that was skipped but it doesn't return any output and the exist status is zero.

Comment: Tables without primary keys and unique indexes cannot get a checksum done because a hash is done based in part on a unique value. In those 10 instances, simply mysqldump those 10 tables from the master and load them into the slave.

Comment: This still doesn't sum up to 145 but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything along those lines in the [**Percona Toolkit Documentation**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-table-checksum.html).

There is something you can do to cheat

## Scenario

- `datadir` is `/var/lib/mysql`
- Master has `test` database
- Slave has `test_slave` database

You could create a symbolic link in one of two ways

## TECHNIQUE #1

On the Master, run

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/test /var/lib/mysql/test_slave
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/test_slave
```

## TECHNIQUE #2

On the Slave (if there is no `test` database), run

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/test_slave /var/lib/mysql/test
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/test
```

## NEXT STEP

Once you created the symbolic link, you can run the checksum against `test`

```
pt-table-checksum --host=localhost --databases=test --max-load=Threads_connected:25 --no-check-replication-filters
```

or against `test_slave`

```
pt-table-checksum --host=localhost --databases=test_slave --max-load=Threads_connected:25 --no-check-replication-filters
```

## EPILOGUE

When done, you can remove the symbolic link.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any idea why "pt-table-checksum" is checking only few tables (please see edit section in question)?

Comment: Are the 40 entries in `percona.checksums` all mismatches ?

Comment: Run this: `cd /var/lib/mysql/test_slave ; ls -l *.frm | wc -l`. This should be 145. Then, run `ls -l | awk '{print $3,$4}' | uniq`. Do you see anything other than `mysql mysql` ?

Comment: There was only one mismatch. Please see "EDIT 2".